# SSH Operation Time Out Trying to Login

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

Please forgive the embarrassingly dumb newb question.

Here's the scenario:

As part of a task I have to SSH into a server and create some files.  I was given the servers name (some.server.com) and an SSH key (id_rsa.username) to use.  I am told to use the username and the provided key to login. Since I am relatively new to the workings of SSH this is what I have done:

I have downloaded id_rsa.username to my Downloads directory.

I have tried loggin in with 
    ssh -i downloads/id_rsa.username username@some.server.com
But I get ssh: connect to host some.server.com  port 22: Operation timed out

I have tried using port 2222 and also 11234 ( I used that port once on a different server).

Is there anything I am doing wrong on my end?  I don't have access the server admin to ask any questions so I have to try to figure this out myself.

Comment: Why the down vote??  I asked an honest question and I have provided what I have tried.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and thus off-topic. Try http://superuser.com/ instead if you have similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I change the rule of ufw, and that rule ban the ssh connect
so run `sudo ufw allow ssh`solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

"Operation timed out" means that you're not making a TCP connection to the remote server. The remote computer may be down, or there may be a firewall blocking access to the the remote server, or your local computer may not have suitable network access. It's not really possible to say what the exact problem is, based on the information here.

If you're in a corporate network, you should contact your local computer support staff for assistance. It's not unheard of for companies to block outgoing SSH from their corporate network.

Otherwise, if you need help troubleshooting network connectivity, you'd probably get better results on [Superuser.](https://superuser.com/)